# Two XML elements with same id

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to modify two TextViews in exactly the same way. I thought I can give them same id and with findViewById() and setText() methods change those TextViews in two lines. But it seems only one TextView is changed.

Is there a way to do this?
Or I have to make different ids for every element, get every element by findViewById() method and set it's text?

Comment: Why would I do this?
I have two LinearLayouts on the widget that are build different (different gravity values of elements). I thought it would be easier to do two different layouts and make one visible and the other gone when needed.

Comment: @Seraphis: this definitely is not the best solution neither the right way. You should change all the needed values via code if something needs to be changed at runtime.

Comment: So the proper way is to make another widget with the same items (ids) but different values of gravity and orientation?

Comment: Ok, I did as I wrote above and it works fine with the same ids. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

View IDs are plain integers, so you can simply have an array of ids you want to change. For example:

```
int[] ids = { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, ... };
for (int id: ids) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(id);
    tv.setText("Hello, World!");
}
```

Of course, it would be best to have `ids` as a static final class member. I.e.:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int[] textViewIDs = {
        R.id.text1,
        R.id.text2,
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I see it's the only solution for my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to define two different ids. There is no way to have a widget with the same id as another one as both are two different and independent widgets.

Answer (score 0):

An id is unique for each View.So cannot be shared. What you can do is have both view ids fetched in the code and have conditons to modify the the text. Like if(id==id1 && id==id2) then edit the text.

Comment: What do you mean by "to have both view ids fetched in the code"? Can You explain me which TextView would be modified in that condition?