# set textsize for multiple textview with same ID

Tags: android, fonts, textview, set

Is it possible to set textsize for multiple textview with same ID ? I have them with android:id :"@+id/lbl" ? Actually I set dp based on folder values/dimen.xml

```
TextView lbl=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl);
lbl.setTextSize(dp);
```

The first textview only get this effect, but the rest of textview dont get this effect. Let me know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it separately as every activty/fragment/adapter has its own layouts (xml). In R.java they would have its own unique number.

```
   android:textSize="24sp"
```

Everytime you add the views in XML, just add the text size

Comment: yes I know how to set in the layout, but I practice to load values from dimens.xml

Comment: android:textSize="@dimen/twenty_two"  <-- you can do that as well

Answer (score 1):

In android platform each view must have a unique id identified by "android:id" attribute of view. Although you are able to define multiple views with same id but android very first declaration and leaves the rest view as having no id.
Lets have an example now:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/response_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/scan_format"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/response_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/response_text"
    android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/response_text"
    android:text="Trepeattet" />
```

here are two textviews with same id,  and now see R.java

```
    public static final int radio=0x7f05002f;
    public static final int response_text=0x7f050040;
    public static final int scan_button=0x7f05003c;
    public static final int scan_content=0x7f05003e;
    public static final int scan_format=0x7f05003d;
```

in R.java only one textview is declared with its id(this hex id is created by platform compiler itself when you first run your code).

So although application does not produce any error in compile time or run time but will not do anything to any other view with same id either except very first one because of only one reference available that belongs to first textview.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4144144/3690154) post here is what you can do:

View IDs are plain integers, so you can simply have an array of ids you want to change. For example:

```
int[] ids = { R.id.lbl1, R.id.lbl2, ... };
for (int id: ids) {
TextView lbl=(TextView) findViewById(id);
lbl.setTextSize(dp);
```

}

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all TextViews of your parent view. Then check their ids in a loop